# Формат даты из бд

Tags: php, mysql

В бд есть поле **`bdate`**. Его тип -- **`date`**. В нём хранятся даты рождения пользователей. Когда я вывожу -- получается ГОД-МЕСЯЦ-ДЕНЬ.

Как вывести дату в формате `00 месяц 1999`?

Например: в бд записано 1984-06-10

Нужно вывести: 10 июня 1984.

Число выводится переменной `$users['bdate']`

Comment: гуглим: SQL FORMAT()

Answer (score 4):

```
SET lc_time_names =  'ru_RU';
SELECT LOWER(DATE_FORMAT(`date_col`, '%d %M %Y')) from `table`;
```

Comment: http://goo.gl/6nljC
Вот тут видно, что по запросу выше, формируется человекапонятная дата и что дружит с русским прекрасно все.

Comment: Ещё бы в нижной регистр - и было бы по-русски :)

Comment: Если обернуть в функцию LOWER(...) то символы преобразуются в нижний регистр. Ответ поправил.

Comment: [Ага](http://ato.su/resizer/i/1/3/3936b60e.png) :)

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно вывести что-то на человеческом языке - читайте из базы `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(bdate)` и преобразовывайте самостоятельно. Стандартное форматирование (что в PHP, что в SQL) не дружит с русским языком, и вместо `10 июня 1984` вы получите `10 июнь 1984` в лучшем случае.